# row_number modifying my code with a geometry update

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a problem with my following view :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.unites_foncieres_test
AS SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ogc_fid,
    foo.code_insee,
    foo.nompro,
    foo.adr_prop,
    foo.cp_prop,
    foo.ville_prop,
    foo.wkb_geometry,
    ( SELECT sum(parcelles.surff) AS surface_fiscale
           FROM dblink('hostaddr=xxx port=xxx dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx'::text, 'SELECT surff, wkb_geometry FROM parcelles'::text) parcelles(surff integer, wkb_geometry geometry(MultiPolygon,2154))
          WHERE st_contains(foo.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles.wkb_geometry))
          GROUP BY foo.wkb_geometry) AS surface_fiscale,
    round(st_area(foo.wkb_geometry)::integer::numeric, 0) AS surface,
    concat(lpad(zae_test.numero_zae::text, 2, '0'::text), '-', lpad(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae_test.numero_zae ORDER BY zae_test.id)::text, 3, '0'::text)) AS code,
    ( SELECT string_agg(btrim(parcelles.refparc::text), ','::text) AS string_agg
           FROM dblink('hostaddr=xxx port=xxx dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx'::text, 'SELECT refparc, wkb_geometry FROM parcelles'::text) parcelles(refparc character varying, wkb_geometry geometry(MultiPolygon,2154))
          WHERE st_contains(foo.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles.wkb_geometry))) AS refparc_liste,
    foo.numero_zae,
    foo.nom_zae
   FROM ( SELECT faa.code_insee,
            faa.nompro,
            faa.adr_prop,
            faa.cp_prop,
            faa.ville_prop,
            faa.numero_zae,
            (st_dump(st_union(faa.wkb_geometry))).geom::geometry(Polygon,2154) AS wkb_geometry,
            faa.nom_zae
           FROM ( SELECT parcelles.ogc_fid,
                    parcelles.wkb_geometry,
                    parcelles.code_insee,
                    parcelles.nompro,
                    parcelles.adr_prop,
                    parcelles.cp_prop,
                    parcelles.ville_prop,
                    zae_1_1.nom AS nom_zae,
                    zae_1_1.numero_zae
                   FROM zae_test zae_1_1,
                    dblink('hostaddr=xxx port=xxx dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx'::text, 'SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry, code_insee, nompro,adr_prop,cp_prop,ville_prop FROM parcelles'::text) parcelles(ogc_fid integer, wkb_geometry geometry(MultiPolygon,2154), code_insee character varying(5), nompro character varying, adr_prop character varying, cp_prop character varying, ville_prop character varying)
                  WHERE st_contains(zae_1_1.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles.wkb_geometry))) faa,
            zae_test zae_1
          GROUP BY faa.nompro, faa.code_insee, faa.adr_prop, faa.cp_prop, faa.ville_prop, faa.numero_zae, faa.nom_zae) foo
     JOIN zae_test ON foo.numero_zae::text = zae_test.numero_zae::text;
```

This view creates property units (unités foncières) . This unités foncières regroup parcels with the same owner that are side by side in each economic activity area (zone d'activité économique = zae).

On the next picture, the blue hard symbol represents parcels and below it in brown the unités foncières made of parcels.  [image: Picture of unités foncières and parcels]

I need, for each unité foncière, to assign a separate code. It's made of the number of the zae to which the unités foncière belongs and a unique number.

```
concat(lpad(zae_test.numero_zae::text, 2, '0'::text), '-', lpad(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae_test.numero_zae ORDER BY zae_test.id)::text, 3, '0'::text)) AS code
```

The problem, it that if I modify the geom of a zae, this code will automatically be regenerated even for the unités foncières that are not included in the modified zae. On the two pictures of the view before and after the update, the 'test_3' zae is modified. The codes of the unités foncières coming from the zae 'test_3' are modified and also the ones coming from the zae 'test_1' even though the geom wasn't modified. Yet, the codes from the unites_foncieres coming from the zae 'test_2' will not change.

Picture of the ZAE before update

[image: Picture of the ZAE before update]

Picture of the ZAE after update

[image: Picture of the ZAE after update]

Table : zae_test

| id | nom | geom | numero_zae |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test_1 | geom | 1 |
| 2 | Test_2 | geom | 2 |
| 3 | Test_3 | geom | 3 |

View before update

| code | refparc_liste | numero_zae | nom_zae |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-001 | ZR0062 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-002 | ZR0063 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-003 | ZR0633,ZR0636,ZR0444,ZR0443,ZR0634,ZR0635,ZR0445 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-004 | ZR0656 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-005 | ZR0438,ZR0439 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-006 | ZR0441 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-007 | ZR0448 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-008 | ZR0440,ZR0452 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-009 | ZR0451 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-010 | ZR0437 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-011 | ZR0657 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-012 | ZR0655 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 02-001 | C0956,C0957 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 02-002 | C0959 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 02-003 | C0958 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 02-004 | C0955 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 03-001 | AD0181,AD0180 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-002 | AD0166 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-003 | AD0173 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-004 | AD0172,AD0171 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-005 | AD0163,AD0164,AD0165 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-006 | AD0179 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-007 | AD0189 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-008 | AD0169 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-009 | AD0177 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-010 | AD0178 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-011 | AD0156 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-012 | AD0176 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-013 | AD0221,AD0220 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-014 | AD0223 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-015 | AD0170 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-016 | AD0186 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-017 | AD0167,AD0168 | 3 | Test_3 |

View after update

| code | refparc_liste | numero_zae | nom_zae |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-001 | ZR0063 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-002 | ZR0655 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-003 | ZR0633,ZR0636,ZR0444,ZR0443,ZR0634,ZR0635,ZR0445 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-004 | ZR0656 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-005 | ZR0438,ZR0439 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-006 | ZR0448 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-007 | ZR0440,ZR0452 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-008 | ZR0451 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-009 | ZR0437 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-010 | ZR0441 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-011 | ZR0062 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 01-012 | ZR0657 | 1 | Test_1 |
| 02-001 | C0956,C0957 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 02-002 | C0959 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 02-003 | C0958 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 02-004 | C0955 | 2 | Test_2 |
| 03-001 | AD0173 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-002 | AD0172,AD0171 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-003 | AD0181,AD0180 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-004 | AD0179 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-005 | AD0169 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-006 | AD0177 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-007 | AD0178 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-008 | AD0189 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-009 | AD0176 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-010 | AD0221,AD0220 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-011 | AD0223 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-012 | AD0170 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-013 | AD0168 | 3 | Test_3 |
| 03-014 | AD0186 | 3 | Test_3 |

And if I modify again the geometry of zae : 'test_3', the view will be exactly as before update. Which means it's not totally random.

Comment: Assigning a feature ID by row_number is an invitation to data corruption, since you are placing data integrity at the mercy of the optimizer, which, without an ORDER BY,  can return rows in whatever order it wants.

Comment: I already use an ORDER BY in the query.
Or maybe my ORDER BY shouldn't be used with my table 'zae_test' but with the table 'parcelles' ?

Comment: Even with an `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause, it's still suboptimal to have the "fid" column be generated anew with each query. Use a natural primary key instead.

Comment: You probably rather want to `ORDER BY` the owner. But a primary key generated by query results over possibly changing core tables may indeed be ambiguous down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One month later I found a solution.

Instead of :

```
concat(lpad(zae_test.numero_zae::text, 2, '0'::text), '-', lpad(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae_test.numero_zae ORDER BY zae_test.id)::text, 3, '0'::text)) AS code,
```

I'm doing :

```
concat(lpad(zae.numero_zae::text, 2, '0'::text), '-', lpad(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae.numero_zae ORDER BY foo.nopro)::text, 3, '0'::text)) AS code,
```

So I'm now using the owner number of the parcel foo.nopro in the ORDER BY.
Now, if I change the geom of my zae, it doesn't change my code.

Here is my complete view :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.mv_izae_unites_foncieres
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ogc_fid,
    foo.code_insee,
    foo.nompro,
    foo.adr_prop,
    foo.cp_prop,
    foo.ville_prop,
    foo.wkb_geometry,
    ( SELECT sum(parcelles.surff) AS surface_fiscale
           FROM dblink('hostaddr=xxx port=xxx dbname=xxx user=talmondais password=xxx'::text, 'SELECT surff, wkb_geometry FROM parcelles'::text) parcelles(surff integer, wkb_geometry geometry(MultiPolygon,2154))
          WHERE st_contains(foo.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles.wkb_geometry))
          GROUP BY foo.wkb_geometry) AS surface_fiscale,
    round(st_area(foo.wkb_geometry)::integer::numeric, 0) AS surface,
    concat(lpad(zae.numero_zae::text, 2, '0'::text), '-', lpad(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae.numero_zae ORDER BY foo.nopro)::text, 3, '0'::text)) AS code,
    ( SELECT string_agg(btrim(parcelles.refparc::text), ','::text) AS string_agg
           FROM dblink('hostaddr=xxx port=xxx dbname=xxx user=talmondais password=xxx'::text, 'SELECT refparc, wkb_geometry FROM parcelles'::text) parcelles(refparc character varying, wkb_geometry geometry(MultiPolygon,2154))
          WHERE st_contains(foo.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles.wkb_geometry))) AS refparc_liste,
    foo.numero_zae,
    foo.nom_zae,
    foo.nopro
   FROM ( SELECT faa.code_insee,
            faa.nompro,
            faa.adr_prop,
            faa.cp_prop,
            faa.ville_prop,
            faa.numero_zae,
            (st_dump(st_union(faa.wkb_geometry))).geom::geometry(Polygon,2154) AS wkb_geometry,
            faa.nom_zae,
            faa.nopro
           FROM ( SELECT parcelles.ogc_fid,
                    parcelles.wkb_geometry,
                    parcelles.code_insee,
                    parcelles.nompro,
                    parcelles.adr_prop,
                    parcelles.cp_prop,
                    parcelles.ville_prop,
                    parcelles.nopro,
                    zae_1_1.nom AS nom_zae,
                    zae_1_1.numero_zae
                   FROM zae zae_1_1,
                    dblink('hostaddr=xxx port=xxx dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx'::text, 'SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry, code_insee, nompro,adr_prop,cp_prop,ville_prop,nopro FROM parcelles'::text) parcelles(ogc_fid integer, wkb_geometry geometry(MultiPolygon,2154), code_insee character varying(5), nompro character varying, adr_prop character varying, cp_prop character varying, ville_prop character varying, nopro character varying)
                  WHERE st_contains(zae_1_1.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles.wkb_geometry))) faa,
            zae zae_1
          GROUP BY faa.nompro, faa.code_insee, faa.adr_prop, faa.cp_prop, faa.ville_prop, faa.numero_zae, faa.nom_zae, faa.nopro) foo
     JOIN zae ON foo.numero_zae::text = zae.numero_zae::text;
```